# Xamarin SwipeView Open Left Item In ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am new to programming, and I am learning by writing small app in Xamarin.

When the button is clicked, I want to open SwipeView without ControlTemplate tag. I am able to open the swipeview, but after using ControlTemplate, I am unable to access the swipeview in the code behind. Swipview is working when I swipe the screen, only I am unable  use below code in the code behind

```
Swipemenu.Open(OpenSwipeItem.LeftItems);
```

when using Control Template tag

```
<ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate>
        <SwipeView x:Name="Swipemenu"  >
                  <SwipeView.Background>

                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource VioletGradientStart}" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{DynamicResource VioletGradientEnd}" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>

            </SwipeView.Background>
           
            <SwipeView.LeftItems >

                <SwipeItems
                    SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="RemainOpen"  >
                    
                    <SwipeItemView >
                       
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical" WidthRequest="250">
                                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                      RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, *" Margin="20,00,00,00"
                RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="&#xf1948;  Dash Board"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None">
                                        
                                        
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>

                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="poduction"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf08d6;  Production"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None" 
                                        
                                        >



                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>



                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf1322;  Maintenance"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="3"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf0b67;  Shedule"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="4"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf0e81;  Emergency"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="5"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf0004;  Profile"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="6"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf0343;  Logout"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>

                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="8"
                                        FontFamily="UIicon"
                                        Text="&#xf0156;"
                                        TextColor="Red"
                                        FontSize="30"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        TextTransform="None"
                                        CornerRadius="100"
                                       
                                        >
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    </Button>


                                </Grid>





                            </StackLayout>


                        </Grid>


                    </SwipeItemView>

                </SwipeItems>


            </SwipeView.LeftItems>


            <StackLayout x:Name="damenucon" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-Bg}" Spacing="0">
            
               
                <!--  Title  -->
                <Button
                    x:Name="HamDash"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    FontFamily="UIicon"
                    Text="&#xF035C;"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="30"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                   Padding="-20,00,00,00"
                   Clicked="HamDash_Clicked">


                </Button>
            
            
            
                <Label
                     Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,16"
                FontFamily="Montserrat-Medium"
                Style="{StaticResource TitleLabelStyle}"
                Text="Daily Production"/>




                <BoxView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-200}" HeightRequest="1" />
                <ContentPresenter />
            
        </StackLayout>
            </SwipeView>
    </ControlTemplate>
 
</ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin provide `GetTemplateChild` to get a named element from a template. The `GetTemplateChild` method should only be called after the OnApplyTemplate method has been called. If you want to call the OnApplyTemplate method, this template should be added for the contentpage.

Override the `OnApplyTemplate` to get the Swipemenu.

```
  public SwipeView Swipemenu;
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Swipemenu = (SwipeView)GetTemplateChild("Swipemenu");
    }
```

And then use the `HamDash_Clicked` event to open.

```
private void HamDash_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Swipemenu.Open(OpenSwipeItem.LeftItems);
    }
```

Get a named element from a template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#get-a-named-element-from-a-template

Comment: Check my updated reply.

Comment: Thanks for the help  ---Wendy Zang