# Resume and modify some graphic elements present in another page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I have created a ControlTemplate in the app.xaml, defining the graphic part, only in the cs I would like to take some elements, to which I have given the name, to assign them the click event, but it signals me that they do not exist in the current context .
Someone who could kindly tell me how to please?
Someone, if possible, modify the source of the webview present in the main page, directly from app.xaml.cs

My code in the template is this:`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderFooterTemplate"><ContentPresenter />
                <StackLayout>
                    <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#DDDDDD" HeightRequest="2" Margin="0" />
                    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                            <StackLayout Background="#c9ced6" HeightRequest="120" MinimumHeightRequest="120" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Spacing="2">
                                <Grid WidthRequest="100" MinimumHeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="#373B53" Padding="10" x:Name="Dashboard">
                                    <Image Source="homeArancione" x:Name="imgDashboard" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="0" />
                                    <Label Text="DASHBOARD" TextColor="#c9ced6" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
                                </Grid></Grid>
```

And in the reference page I recall it like this:

```
ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderFooterTemplate}"
```

Graphically it works, but in the cs is I can't modify the texts to the labels or assign click events to the elements because it tells me that they don't exist in the current context

Comment: Without some sample code we can't help you. Let's see your xaml and xaml.cs

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Tell me if this is clearer or if you might need more information

Comment: Try assigning a name too. `x:Name="Footer"`. And call it with Footer.WhateverYouWantToDo

Comment: I gave it a name, but in the cs if I try to recall it, nothing changes, I still can't find the belonging objects

Comment: Are you trying to access it from App.xaml.cs or somewhere else?

Comment: At the moment from App.xaml.cs, but I would like to be able to access it from other pages if possible later

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following the logic here. Why is your ControlTemplate in the App.xaml? You need your ContentTemplate to be in a ContentView. And then consume it from wherever you want. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text or trigger the click event of the label in `ControlTemplate`, you could use the `GestureRecognizers`. The  `x:Name` could not be found in the `ControlTemplate` directly.

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderFooterTemplate">
            <!--<ContentPresenter />-->
            <StackLayout>
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#DDDDDD" HeightRequest="2" Margin="0" />
                <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                        <StackLayout Background="#c9ced6" HeightRequest="120" MinimumHeightRequest="120" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Spacing="2">
                            <Grid WidthRequest="100" MinimumHeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="#373B53" Padding="10" x:Name="Dashboard">
                                <Image Source="homeArancione" x:Name="imgDashboard" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="0" />
                                <Label Text="DASHBOARD" TextColor="#c9ced6" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Code behind: App.xaml.cs

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------");
        var label = sender as Label;
        label.Text = "Hello";
    }
```

**Update:**

> update the text of the label as soon as the page loads, without
> having to click

Xamarin provide `GetTemplateChild` to get a named element from a template. The `GetTemplateChild` method should only be called after the OnApplyTemplate method has been called. If you want to call the OnApplyTemplate method, this template should be added for the contentpage.

You could refer to the thread i done before.
[Xamarin SwipeView Open Left Item In ControlTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131642/xamarin-swipeview-open-left-item-in-controltemplate/70166575#70166575)

Comment: Ok, as soon as I can I try, thank you very much.
I should also add the click event to the buttons, which I imagine works in the same way, but which should change the source to the webview of the page contained in the content presenter

Comment: Please have a try. If you have any issue about this, please feel free o let me know.

Comment: Thanks again it works great for what I have to do, but still other things remain that I did not understand how to do:
1) update the text of the label as soon as the page loads, without having to click
2) by clicking on a button in the controltemplate, modify the source of the webview present in the contentpresenter
3) create a gesturerecognizer that allows me to modify the source of other images, always present in the controltemplate

Comment: I have updated the reply with 1). Please check it.

Comment: For the 2) and 3), it need more code with contentpresenter, source and so on. You could post a new case with details.